# Prevent Visual Studio From opening a new Tab group

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use a side by Side tab group setup and it works great about 90% of the time.  However every once in a while VS decides it doesn't like my tab groups and every time I preform an action that opens a source file it creates a third tab group.  All subsequent opens then go to that new tab group.  Is there any way to prevent this behavior.